# How to create Discriminated Union with private constructor?

Tags: generics, f#

I have the following DU:

```
type Vector<'T when 'T: (static member (+): 'T * 'T -> 'T) and 'T: (static member (*): 'T * 'T -> 'T)> =
        private
        | Vector of ('T list)
```

I've tried creating a factory function like this (within the same module):

```
let inline from_list (xs: 'T list) =
        match xs.Length with
        | 0 -> failwith "Cannot create a zero-length Vector"
        | _ -> Vector.Vector xs
```

but it gives me compilation error:

> error FS1113: The value 'from_list' was marked inline but its
> implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is
> not sufficiently accessible 1>

I've also tried defining it as a "static inline member" function but result is the same.

Comment: The answer is no, https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/161 . But your example is a (popular but) bad way to do things: the DU only one case (i.e. doesn't "discriminate") and the type name and case name are conflated. You are using the wrong construct and you should use a class/struct, which will also mean you can make the default constructor private and enforce an alternate constructor.

Comment: Yeah, in this case a struct wrapper is ideal.

Comment: not something ive ever done...there is this https://trustbit.tech/blog/2021/05/01/alternate-ways-of-creating-single-case-discriminated-unions-in-f-sharp

Comment: Thanks, the argument about discriminated union not actually discriminating anything is quite convincing. But why is that if I remove the T constraints from the Vector definition and remove the "inline" from the method definition, it does compile?